# How to switch from using RigidBody.SleepVelocity to RigidBody.SleepThreshold in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

So I am working with an old project written in Unity 4.x and having to make it work in 5.x with some of the physics changes.

There are several calls to RigidBody.SleepVelocity, which according to the api documentation, is now no longer supported.

The replacement is RigidBody.SleepThreshold.

I kind of understand the differences between the two, but I don't know how to convert from using the old system to that of the new.

How would I convert from using SleepVelocity to Threshold?

(btw I'm working in JS but I could read the equivilent C#)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation `Rigidbody.sleepVelocity` represents velocity, and `Rigidbody.sleepThreshold` represents energy. So if understand correctly all you have to do is to find some multiplier to multiply it on your old velocity value, so the result energy value will cause same behaviour.

To calculated object's energy you can use this:

```
 float E = rigidbody.mass * rigidbody.velocity.sqrMagnitude * 0.5f;
```

Just find suitable `E` value and use it for your `Rigidbody.sleepThreshold`

Comment: Is that all it is?  I did think it should be an easy change.  but does the mass not come into it.

Comment: oh, yeah. fixed the formula